# fixed header above not fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

So I have this markup:

```
<header>
    <h1> Movy </h1>
    <span class="tools" style='display: none'>
        <button id='edit'>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </button>
        <button id='check'>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
        <button id='trash'>
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</header>

<nav id='nav'>
    <ul class='navbar-nav'>
        <li id='came-out'>Came Out</li>
        <li class='active' id='coming-soon'>Coming Soon</li>
        <li id='watched'>Watched</li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
...
```

And I want the header to be fixed, and the navbar to scroll. 
So I added this to the CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

nav { 
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

But [the result](http://jsbin.com/jigewo/4/edit?html,css,output) is not what I wanted. I tried adding `clear: both` to every element but nothing has changed.
**EDIT:** [This](http://jsbin.com/jigewo/5/edit?html,css,output) is how it should look like, but the header should be fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by '*and the navbar to stay as it is*'? Should it be fixed, or should it scroll? Maybe you can add an image that points out the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for...

Comment: @LinkinTED You are right, I'm sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: Should the navbuttons scroll with the page, or be fixed as well??

Comment: They should scroll with the page, as I mentioned in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the height of your header to a fixed height (in em or in px). Then add a padding top to your body with the same number.

```
body {
    background: #e5e5e5;;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    color: #444;
    height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

header {
    background: #4285f4;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And take away the margin of the nav.

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5qaztaLh/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div for your nav, and the rest of the page, and set a margin-top to clear the header div.

```
<header>
    <h1> Movy </h1>
    <span class="tools" style='display: none'>
    <button id='edit'>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </button>
    <button id='check'>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </button>
    <button id='trash'>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</header>

<div id='wrapper'>
<nav id='nav'>
    <ul class='navbar-nav'>
        <li id='came-out'>Came Out</li>
        <li class='active' id='coming-soon'>Coming Soon</li>
        <li id='watched'>Watched</li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top:0;
}

.wrapper { 
  margin-top: 3em;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: The result is the same: [link](http://jsbin.com/jigewo/6/edit?html,css,output). But thanks for the quick answer though.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qifuhizixuxu/1 - You want (but don't need) to make the wrapper display as a block, then add top:0 to the header part, and increase the margin-top of wrapper until it's in the place you want

Comment: Why wrap a block element inside a another block element? Makes no sense to me... you can easily style the nav the same as the wrapper... no need for an extra element.

Comment: It would make sense to add a wrapper for all other elements underneath the header to go into. That's just how I work. Generally, you'll have the page in a wrapper anyway, and if a part of it gets taken out and fixed, I find it useful to then wrap the remainder of the page to keep it all in one block.